# How hide cell wile reordering TableVirew

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

Aim is to hide cell which is reordering when reordering animation starts and show cell when reordering animation stops.

[image]

PS 
When you moving cell, it's alpha is changed, i think there is a way to set alpha to 0, but how? It is necessary for me to hide else shadow of moving cell, because i try show diferent picture instead moving cell.

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question? If an answer helped you solve your problem, please remember to accept it. It is ok to answer your own questions, however you should not crease multiple answers. You can edit an answer to add more relevant information. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/about if you want to find out more about the stackoverflow basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourtableviewcell setHidden:YES];
```

If you want to fade it away, animate the alpha to 0 first.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
yourtableviewcell.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: In what method i should use [yourtableviewcell setHidden:YES]

Answer (score 0):

I used next code in my CustomCell class and result is in the picture. Cell is hidden and it's good.

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"Drugging");    // Dragging started
        self.hidden=YES;
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Drugging End");     // Dragging ended
    self.hidden=NO;
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass ([view class]) rangeOfString:@"ReorderControl"].location != NSNotFound) {    // UITableViewCellReorderControl
            if (view.gestureRecognizers.count == 0) {
                UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
                gesture.cancelsTouchesInView    = NO;
                gesture.minimumPressDuration    = 0.150;
                [view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[There answer to shadow question](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/removing-reorder-cell-shadows-from-a-uitableview)